# Content Block types kicking out code

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

we're creating content block 'templates' which work fine when created as an html content block. However when we create as a free form content block it's kicking out some of our code.

Here's the code:

```
                <!-- Two columns with title, paragraph copy and CTAs #v4 start -->
                <div title="Two columns with title, paragraph copy and CTAs">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="min-width:100% !important;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="center" class="MainText DoubleOuter" style="title:Main Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.2; color:#131C1C; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px ;">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="CC_NoEdit">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <th align="left" class="MainText MobBlock MobFullWidth CC_NoEdit" style="font-weight:normal;display:inline-table !important;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;float:left; title:Main Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.2; color:#131C1C;">
                                            <div>
                                                <table width="290" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="MobFullWidth CC_NoEdit">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" class="MainText DoubleColumn" style="title:Main Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.2; color:#131C1C; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px ;">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <div class="HeadingText" style="title:Heading Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:1.1; font-weight: bold ; color:#520d5d;">Left Title<br>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="CC_NoEdit">
                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" style="height:1px;line-height:1px; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px ;" class="HeadingDividerPadding">
                                                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="CC_NoEdit">
                                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                                    <td height="1" align="left" valign="middle" style="height:1px;line-height:1px; padding-bottom: 0px; background:#520d5d;" class="HeadingDivider HeadingDividerBGColor">
                                                                                        <img alt="" width="30" height="1" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" src="http://img.constantcontact.com/letters/images/1101116784221/S.gif" style="display: block;">
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                                <div>Paragraph copy, try and keep roughly equal in both columns. Hit enter at the end of bullet point 3 to add another bullet. Delete any you don’t need.<br>
                                                                    <ul style="padding:0 0 0 20px;margin:0;">
                                                                        <br>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">First bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">Second bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">Third bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                    <br>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:auto !important; border: 1px solid #520d5d;" class="ButtonRound ButtonBGColor CC_NoEdit primaryColorBorder">
                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="ButtonText Button" style="title:Button Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.2; color:#2c3e50; padding:8px 25px 8px 25px;">
                                                                            <div><a href="#" class="ButtonText" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.2; color:#520d5d;">Read more ›</a></div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th align="left" class="MainText MobBlock MobFullWidth CC_NoEdit" style="font-weight:normal;display:inline-table !important;padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;float:left; title:Main Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.2; color:#131C1C;">
                                            <div>
                                                <table width="289" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="MobFullWidth CC_NoEdit">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td align="left" valign="top" class="MainText DoubleColumn" style="title:Main Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.2; color:#131C1C; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px ;">
                                                            <div>
                                                                <div class="HeadingText" style="title:Heading Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height:1.1; font-weight: bold ; color:#520d5d;">Right Title<br>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="CC_NoEdit">
                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" style="height:1px;line-height:1px; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px ;" class="HeadingDividerPadding">
                                                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="CC_NoEdit">
                                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                                    <td height="1" align="left" valign="middle" style="height:1px;line-height:1px; padding-bottom: 0px; background:#520d5d;" class="HeadingDivider HeadingDividerBGColor">
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                                <div>Paragraph copy, try and keep roughly equal in both columns. Hit enter at the end of bullet point 3 to add another bullet. Delete any you don’t need.<br>
                                                                    <ul style="padding:0 0 0 20px;margin:0;">
                                                                        <br>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">First bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">Second bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                        <li style="margin:0;">Third bullet point with a <a href="https://www.cipd.co.uk" target="_BLANK" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#520d5d;margin:0;">link</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                    <br>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:auto !important; border: 1px solid #520d5d;" class="ButtonRound ButtonBGColor CC_NoEdit primaryColorBorder">
                                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="ButtonText Button" style="title:Button Text; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.2; color:#2c3e50; padding:8px 25px 8px 25px;">
                                                                            <div><a href="#" class="ButtonText" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.2; color:#520d5d;">Read more ›</a></div>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody></table>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                            </div>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                <!-- Two columns with title, paragraph copy and CTAs end -->
```

And the code that's being removed is some of the styles on this  under the Right title:

```
<td height="1" align="left" valign="middle" style="height:1px;line-height:1px; padding-bottom: 0px; background:#520d5d;" class="HeadingDivider HeadingDividerBGColor">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite its name, the `free form block` is not meant to preserve your content as is. It's actually the opposite: it uses [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) experience, which some users less familiar with HTML/CSS will find helpful. There is additional processing and validation being done, by CKEditor, the block, the editor, that can impact and modify your code.

In your case, since you want to paste HTML, you want to stick to the `html block`.

Comment: Thanks for that, however what the html block doesn't allow my marketers to do is edit using the wysiwyg - which is what I'm after. But without the code being kicked out.

Answer (score 0):

We've been experiencing the same issue and have the same reasons for using free form blocks as you. I have an open ticket with Salesforce on the issue and have been told the fix is scheduled to be deployed in January 2018. I keep finding new examples of code being changed/deleted which is very frustrating. I don't know details on what the fix is or if it will actually fix all our problems but I have to be hopeful.

I didn't know the free form block wasn't meant to preserve content, that's a bummer as it seemed as if it could be the best of both worlds. In all my conversations with them over my issue, this intent was never brought up.